# Animate a particular marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I insert markers from an array by using a loop and I also include button which zooms to a particular marker. So far so good.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/na9Ha/)**

Now I'd like to animate the marker which I zoom to for 3 seconds. I know I should use the function

```
marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
```

but I can't figure out how to bind the action to a particular marker. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep a reference to the marker objects you create.

```
var marker_refs = [];

function initialize() {
    ...
    for(...) {
        marker_refs[i] = new google.maps.Marker(...);

    ...
}
```

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/na9Ha/2/